# Each user has different 'structure' using only one table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do it like this:

Every single user can choose fields (like structures on MySQL) where this fields can handle their respective value, it's like doing a DB inside a DB.
But how can I do it using a single table?
(not talking about user accounts etc where I should be able to use a pointer to his own "structure")
Do something like: varchar Key where register something like "Name:asd" where PHP explode : to get the respective structure ('name' in this case) and the respective value? ('asd')
Use BLOB? can someone turn the light on for me? I don't know how to do something where works better than my current explanation...

I know my text is confuse and sorry for any bad english.

EDIT:
Also, they could add multiple keys/"structures" where accepts a new value
And they are not able to see the Database or Tables, they still normal users
My server does not support Postogre

Comment: Are you sure there will be absolutely no relations, pre filled select boxes etc?

Comment: What's the problem about having one of these? I still able to do it on "userinfo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should create two tables.

1. with the user info
2. with 3 fields (userid, key and value)

Each user has 1 record in the first table. Each user can have 0 or more records in the second table. This will ensure you can still search the data and that users can easily add more key/value pairs when needed.

Comment: Two "databases"? I think you mean tables?

Comment: @OcasoProtal Hey it's still pretty early here :) Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer. Two tables and a join query.

Answer (score 1):

Don't start building a database in a database. In this case, since the user makes the field by himself there is no relation between the fields as I understand? In that case it would make sense to take a look at the NoSQL databases since they seem to fit very good for this kind of situations.

Another thing to check is something like:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/hstore.html

Do not try to build tables like: records, fields, field types etc. That's a bad practice and should not be needed.

For a more specific answer on your wishes we need a bit more info about the data the user is storing.

Answer (score 1):

While i think the rational answer to this question is the one given by PeeHaa, if you really want the data to fit into one table you could try saving a serialized PHP array in one of the fields. Check out [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

> Generates a storable representation of a value
>
> This is useful for storing or passing PHP values around without losing
>   their type and structure.

This method is discouraged as it is not at all scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table with key-value pairs.  So three columns:

- user id
- key ("name")
- value ("asd")

Add an index on *user id*, so that you can query a user's attributes easily.  If you wanted to query all users with the same properties, then you could add a second index on *key* and/or *value*.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using a programming language also to get the data and present them.

You can have a single table which has a varchar field. Then you store the serialized data of the field structure and their value in that field. When you want to get the structure, query the data and De-serialize that varchar field data.

As per my knowledge every programming language supports serialization and De-serialization.

Edited : This is not a scalable option.

Comment: Although this is possible please note that this is discouraged.

Comment: @PeeHaa thanks, you are correct. It is not a scalable option. I just edited post.